# Was the name 'Valerie' used during the Regency Era (1811-1836)?

Tags: 19th-century, england, united-kingdom, names

I am working on a novel that takes place in England during the [Regency Era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regency_era) (1811-1836, the era right before the Victorian Era). I was wondering if you know if the name 'Valerie' or 'Valeria' existed in the Regency Era or maybe the Georgian Era? I am thinking about naming one of my characters as Valerie. Thanks. If anyone could please answer I would truly appreciate that.

Comment: Google NGrams help. [English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Valerie%2CValeria&year_start=1714&year_end=1850&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CValerie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CValeria%3B%2Cc0) and [French](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Valerie%2CValeria&year_start=1714&year_end=1850&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CValerie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CValeria%3B%2Cc0) - sources can be checked via the links at bottom left. Add a common name (eg Charlotte) to see relative usage.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Google NGrams (in this case at least) isn't reliable. I found several cases of 'Valerio' when checking the results, as well as 'Valerian'. Also, restricting it to British sources only also doesn't work as at least half of the results for the Regency period were actually US publications.

Comment: @LarsBosteen Lacking a time machine or anciem library nothing is liable to be fully accurate :-). aka, yes, indeed :-). It was a suggested lead. As noted " sources can be checked via the links at bottom left" . I have on on occasion found that a look through NGRam sources shows what appears to be an excellent match turns out to be use of the target words in an unexpected manner. On other occasions it confirms the result. I gave two links (British English & French) - a serious use would require a fairly serious amount of delving.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I did consider mentioning the NGRam results in my answer but, after having to discard so many links from them as 'false positives', decided the results appeared to be just too unreliable. But you're right about it being a useful starting point, and some of the links were productive.

Comment: @LarsBosteen For interest - the reason that I spent any time at all on this is that my wife's name is Valerie :-)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon It's a nice name, and I was surprised to find that it didn't really catch on until (it seems) the 1930s.

Comment: @mariaAlessiaN - Thank you for a question that has inspired some interesting scholarship.

Answer (score 26):

**The names Valeria and Valerie were not in *common* use in Britain during the Georgian era, but they were certainly known** by some via Saint [Valerie of Limoges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valerie_of_Limoges) and also because Valerie (in particular) was in use in European aristocracy and literature (both British and continental works translated into English) in the 18th and 19th centuries.

**Valerie** and **Valeria** are not mentioned in this article, [Georgian Era Names](http://victorian-era.org/georgian-era-facts/georgian-era-names.html#:%7E:text=Some%20of%20these%20names%20are,literature%20from%20the%20Georgian%20Era.), and nor do they appear on this [list of 19th century names](https://www.bryndonovan.com/2014/12/08/name-those-regency-era-characters/), nor on this list of "[some of the most popular choices for Georgian parents in Britain](https://www.britishbabynames.com/blog/2013/01/gorgeously-georgian.html)" (though there are a few surprising ones such as Keziah and Theodosia). Nor is there any mention of **Valeria** or **Valerie** in the period following the Georges; see Amy M. Hasfjord's dissertation *[New Influences on Naming Patterns in Victorian Britain](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/48841727.pdf)*.

Neither **Valerie** nor **Valeria** appear to have much of a [history of use in England](https://www.britishbabynames.com/blog/links-to-name-data.html): the names do not appear on any of the popular name lists from the late 14th century, the Elizabethan period, the time of the restoration, the top 50 names of 1700 or even the [top 200 names of 1840](https://www.britishbabynames.com/blog/2018/08/top-200-most-popular-names-in-england-and-wales-in-1840-part-1.html) (just after your target period). Not until the late 1920s or early 1930s does **Valerie** break into the [top 100 girls names](https://www.britishbabynames.com/blog/2011/06/1934.html). However, Chaucer did use **Valerie** in his *[Canterbury Tales](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=4LMDAAAAQAAJ&pg=RA1-PA175&dq=%22valerie%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjHhfqTyLjqAhVMc3AKHSt1BVQ4ChDoATAFegQIBhAC#v=onepage&q=%22valerie%22&f=false)*, while Shakespeare (in *[Coriolanus](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/100/100-h/100-h.htm)*) and the poet (and Poet Laureate) [William Whitehead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Whitehead_(poet)) (1715-85) (in his play *[Roman Father](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=vh8AAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA632&dq=%22valerie%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjSs9jbyLjqAhVX7WEKHXm6Cys4FBDoATAGegQICBAC#v=onepage&q=%22valerie%22&f=false)*) both used **Valeria**.

Thus, I wouldn't rule out the use of **Valerie** or **Valeria** as a girl's name. **Valerie** also [appears in French literature during the period of the French Revolution](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=aAUz_C-iBRUC&pg=PA135&lpg=PA135&dq=french%20aristocrat%20valerie&source=bl&ots=OdnbLIU4yW&sig=ACfU3U1wu_DlswCH2spmOLt1Sf33bEWmjA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjfy8zbjbjqAhWTA4gKHcpoD7EQ6AEwDHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=french%20aristocrat%20valerie&f=false), a time when many French aristocrats were fleeing to Britain, and [**Valerie** was 'imported' from France](https://public.oed.com/blog/personal-names-and-the-development-of-english/) (although it was not particularly popular there either for long periods at least - see [here](http://www.ellipsis.cx/%7Eliana/names/french/latefrench.html) and [here](https://www.behindthename.com/name/valerie/top/france), for example). Perhaps the most notable use of **Valerie** was for Baroness [Barbara von Krüdener](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbara_von_Kr%C3%BCdener)'s [best-selling](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43801518?seq=1) book *[**Valérie**, ou Lettres de Gustave de Linar à Ernest de G....](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6515252n)*, first published in French in 1804 and "[soon translated into Dutch, English, German and Russia](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25480355?seq=1)". In the book, **Valérie** is a countess in a loveless marriage with a much older man, but her behaviour is beyond reproach.

[image]

*Image source: [BNF](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6515252n/f7.item.zoom)*

Some '**Valeries**' that cropped up while searching include the American-born British socialite **[Valerie, Lady Meux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valerie,_Lady_Meux)** (b. 1847), the Swiss writer [**Valérie de Gasparin**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Val%C3%A9rie_de_Gasparin) (b. 1813), the Viennese [**Countess Valerie Erdödy**](http://www.past-to-present.com/photoexponew.cfm?reference=G12613) (uncertain birth date but a young lady in 1869) and the Archduchess [**Marie Valerie of Austria**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archduchess_Marie_Valerie_of_Austria#Ancestry) (b. 1868), who was usually called **Valerie** rather than Marie. Given the extent of inter-marriage among European royalty, it seems plausible (if unusual and perhaps exotic even) for an English aristocratic lady to have the name **Valerie** or even **Valeria** (though you haven't stated your character's social class).

Comment: Good thinking with the jump to the French Revolution!

Comment: @gktscrk Thanks. This is actually pretty difficult to research!

Comment: This is the trifecta of a perfect answer.  Answers(1) the question (2) how to resolve similar questions and (3) the need to ask the question.  well done.

Comment: @Mark C.Wallace Thanks. Comments like this make the effort worthwhile, and I learnt a new word - trifecta.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't appear to be a common name in the era, but it did exist in England

From ancestry.co.uk, I found only the following entries in baptism records from 1811-1831:  Valorie Blower and Valeria Wright. The reference to Valerie Mc Morione Evans (as shown in the screenshot below) appears to have arisen from an incorrect transcription, as she was actually born in 1913.

From FreeBMD.org.uk (which starts in 1835), the earliest I found was Valerie Francisca Ashton, baptised Q1, 1840.

[image]

EDIT: I searched earlier dates and found some other references as below:

- Valeria Jones, Baptised 1791
- Susanna Valerie Garrard, born 1787
- Valeria Josepha Cayetana De Urrutia, born 1777, Co Durham
- Valeria Antonia Monroi, baptised 1762, Somerset
- Valere Ballard, baptised 1718, Lincs
- Valeria Marcelo, baptised 1709, Co Durham

Comment: Nice finds +1, and interesting to see the variations in spelling/forms. I'm curious about Valerie Evans who appears to have been baptized at the age of 86! Better late than never I suppose...

Comment: @LarsBosteen That bothered me too, so I'm doing a bit more digging and I'm starting to have my doubts about whether that one has been wrongly transcribed actually. I think she was actually born on 27/05/1913, which would make much more sense.  Also her middle name was probably McMorrene. I'll edit my answer again.

Comment: Well, you have others which look perfectly legit so not a major problem I think. My search of about 25 volumes of Parish Registers for (mostly) 17th century to (mostly) 1812 didn't produce a single hit for either Valerie or Valeria so you've done well to dig up the ones you have. Between our answers, we now know that the names were definitely used, but very rarely.